# Reindent() in timeit module, help('timeit') does not show functionname. Why?

Tags: python, function, module

The following function which is located in the timeit module (Python(2.7) Standard Library) does not show when I do help('timeit').

```
def reindent(src, indent):
    """Helper to reindent a multi-line statement."""
    return src.replace("\n", "\n" + " "*indent)
```

When I define a function in a module and I call help('modulename'), than functions can be seen in the help()-output. Function names starting with a single underscore don't show up when calling help(). But the reindent function does not have a leading underscore and yet it doesn't show in the help output. Why?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the module there is a variable `__all__` defined:

```
__all__ = ["Timer"]
```

that limits what is imported from timeit. See for example [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) a description of `__all__`. If you comment the line, help gives more info on Data and FUnctions